# windows 10: hotkey bring up a window that has a notification

Tags: windows-10

Windows supports a notification feature where some minimized (not currently in view) applications give the user a notification. Usually this consists of a sound effect accompanied by the application's icon in the taskbar flashing orange.

Is there a Windows hotkey that will display the notifying application, i.e. as if the user clicked its icon on the taskbar? I'm not too good with Windows terminology so it's hard for me to specify my problem. Perhaps someone knows what I mean and can edit my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are referring to the Launch taskbar shortcuts:

Press the Windows Key and then on a number key (1 through 0) to open the first ten
taskbar shortcuts/windows, in order.

This works up through 0, which opens the 10th shortcut,
working as a toggle, so a second use will minimize again the application.